Reading / understanding the context of query_abort extended events trace with SQL CallStackResolver
We've decided to test and perhaps implement the new query_abort extended events trace on all our database servers to learn more about our timeout queries. Currently, we use the rpc_completed event with a status=2 filter.
We will use the SQLCallStackResolver tool as detailed in this Microsoft video and use the task_callstack_rva column processed by the tool.
Here is one of the traces we have from a SELECT statement:
00 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
01 YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
00 SqlDK!ThreadScheduler::SwitchWorker
01 SqlDK!SOS_Scheduler::Switch
02 SqlDK!SOS_Scheduler::SuspendNonPreemptive
03 SqlDK!WaitableBase::Wait
04 sqllang!TDSSNIClient::WriteStatus
05 sqllang!WaitOnWriteAsyncToFinish
06 sqllang!write_data
07 sqllang!flush_buffer
08 sqllang!CTds74::SendRowImpl
09 SqlTsEs!CEsExec::GeneralEval4
0a sqllang!CXStmtQuery::ErsqExecuteQuery
0b sqllang!CXStmtSelect::XretExecute
0c sqllang!CExecStmtLoopVars::ExecuteXStmtAndSetXretReturn
0d sqllang!CMsqlExecContext::ExecuteStmts<1,0>
0e sqllang!CMsqlExecContext::FExecute
0f sqllang!CSQLSource::Execute
10 sqllang!process_request
11 sqllang!process_commands_internal
12 sqllang!process_messages
13 SqlDK!SOS_Task::Param::Execute
14 SqlDK!SOS_Scheduler::RunTask
15 SqlDK!SOS_Scheduler::ProcessTasks
16 SqlDK!Worker::EntryPoint
17 SqlDK!ThreadScheduler::RunWorker
18 SqlDK!SystemThreadDispatcher::ProcessWorker
19 SqlDK!SchedulerManager::ThreadEntryPoint
<frame id="28" address="0x776D11E7" />
1d WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
1e ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ

As far as I can understand, the query is being processed and enters into multiple states & waits, such as assignment to a scheduler for example. But how does this information help us understand what caused the timeout? In fact, it seems to me that everything is going smoothly.


But how does this information help us understand what caused the timeout? In fact, it seems to me that everything is going smoothly.

A callstack doesn't have any context to it (you can't see the state of anything), it's just the path the thread took as part of that program. Sometimes these are helpful, sometimes they aren't.
In this case, the callstack is fairly benign, you're correct. You'll have to use your logical power of deduction to figure out what may have happened based on the client application, SQL Logs, and any other data available which may help.
Frames 0x19-0x13 are boiler plate task execution.
Frames 0x12-0x10 are boiler plate for processing requests incoming to the server.
Frames 0x0f-0x0a are just processing a select statement from a language source.
Frames 0x08-0x03 are sending data back to the client and waiting for the data to be sent or an acknowledgement they have been received.
Frames 0x02-0x00 are moving this worker out of running and to suspended (waiting) while swapping in a new runnable worker (or the idle thread if there are no runnable items).
If you were to take a few wild guesses based on the above data with no context, it could be that the connection was broken, the client (or driver) sent an attention, the wait on the IO took too long and timed out which aborted itself, etc.
How this helps? Not sure, depends on how much data you have collected from the client or other tools. Much like a network capture, only getting data from one side is generally not very helpful, you'll need data from both sides at the same time to understand what each side thought and where/why the problem may be occurring.
